# Problems with wilcard

Tags: snakemake

I have tried multple solutons in the platform but none seems to work. I can't seem to wrap my around the error   AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'sample'

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
sample_csv = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "samples.csv")
sample_table = pd.read_csv(sample_csv).set_index('sample', drop=False)
def get_fq1(wildcards):
    return sample_table.loc[wildcards.sample, 'fastq1']
def get_fq2(wildcards):
    return sample_table.loc[wildcards.sample, 'fastq2']
def get_fq_files_dict(wildcards):
    return {
        "r1" : sample_table.loc[wildcards.sample, 'fastq1'],
        "r2" : sample_table.loc[wildcards.sample, 'fastq2'],
    }

rule fastp:
    input:
        unpack(get_fq_files_dict)
    output:
        expand(base_dir + "/trimmed/{sample}_trimmed.{r}.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES_f, # This is refined elsewhere, r=['_1','_2'])
    shell:
        """
        echo {input} # This is just a decoy command
        """
```

This code throws me the error
`AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'sample'`

Does anybody have an idea what is not right?

Comment: Check the documentation.  Because you're using an `expand` function, the `{sample}` does not declare a wildcard.  https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#helper-functions-for-defining-input-and-output-files

Comment: Yes. I went through that bit. So how would I ensure to retain this function get_fq_files_dict(wildcards) because I want to use it for other rules while still getting files of the specified pattern at the output?

Comment: All that Python code at the top runs before you hit the snakemake stuff and so wildcards doesn't yet exist. You may want to work through some tutorials first. It should be pointed out that Python code at the start runs first if outside of rules.

Comment: The `samples` reference should be used in the input directive so you can use the same reference in the output. This snippet you provided is incomplete and overly complex to give you much help other than refer you to tutorials such as [here for one close to what you are attempting to dp](https://hackmd.io/7k6JKE07Q4aCgyNmKQJ8Iw?view), and [here for a more general tutorial](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/workflows-snakemake/) that may help you better understand how to use wildcards in snakemake.